# Enable SNMP Remotely

Tags: windows, snmp

I have a handful of Windows servers that I would like to enable SNMP on.  However, they are all remote virtual machines so there is no way to use the installation CD's for the required files that SNMP wants to install itself with because whenever I try to enable SNMP Windows always looks for an installation path to find them.

My question is, is there an easy way to make these files accessible across the network?  If so, what is the best way to do this?  Can I rip the i386 folder from a Windows install disc to a folder and share it?

I have also pondered sharing an optical drive on a local machine across the network or possibly just using net-snmp but don't know if that will work since I have barely any SNMP experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> there is no way to use the installation CD's for the required files

Share the `i386` folder (or even the entire CD) over the network, like a normal folder, and point the VMs to it when asked. All Windows cares about is the files inside.

Comment: This might sound really dumb, but does it matter which windows disc is used.  i.e. do I *have* to use a server 2003 disc for servers or would an xp disc work?

Comment: @jmreicha: For a system service, I'm sure it matters.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to successfully install SNMP, for Windows 2003 Server, which requires the "second CD" or "i386" folder to complete the installation. Rather than finding and transferring that large amount or finding a way to mount it from a remote location. I've now just packed up my own SNMP requirements folder for when installing SNMP for Windows 2003. The required files, found in the i386 folder, include:

```
accserv.mib
apver.vbs
authserv.mib
dhcp.mib
evntagnt.dll
evntcmd.exe
evntwin.exe
ftpctrs.h2
ftpctrs.ini
ftp.mib
ftpmib.dll
hostmib.dll
hostmib.mib
http.mib
iis6.cab
inetsrv.mib
ipforwd.mib
lmmib2.dll
lmmib2.mib
mcastmib.mib
mib_ii.mib
mipx.mib
mripsap.mib
msft.mib
msipbtp.mib
msiprip2.mib
nipx.mib
rfc2571.mib
smierrsm.dll
smierrsy.dll
smi.mib
snmp.exe
snmpmib.dll
snmpreg.mof
snmpsmir.dll
snmpsmir.mof
snmpstup.dll
snmptrap.exe
snmp.zip
wfospf.mib
wins.mib
```

The only one I was not able to find was apver.vbs. I had to track that down online. I zipped it up and shared it to myself for easy access/deployment when needed. It's roughly 500KB compared to the 600MB I would need if finagling the "required" CD.

[Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20140603172311/http://www.netexpertise.eu/en/windows/snmp-files.html)